# Android File.mkdirs() not working without error

Tags: android

I copied the following piece of code from a graphhopper demo app, but when I use it in a new app it doesn't work.

```
        boolean greaterOrEqKitkat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    if (greaterOrEqKitkat) {
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            logUser("GraphHopper is not usable without an external storage!");
            return;
        }
        mapsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/folder/maps/");
    } else
        mapsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/folder/maps/");


    if (!mapsFolder.exists()){
        mapsFolder.mkdirs();}
```

I also added the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm completely baffled why this works in the demo app, but not in the app I'm writing. I hope someone can help me solve this issue.

Comment: CatLog error please !

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not getting any errors, the folder is just not being created. I'm not receiving any error, I'm completely baffled.

Comment: did you check for writing permission at run time ?

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs as it returs false if it cannot create the dir(s). Do not continue with the code but display a toast saying so and return.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly, I did not grant the permissions needed on the device I was testing on. Thanks TK52 for pointing me in the right direction to check these!